# Hooking up UGEE 19" Graphics Monitor to my Lenovo 23" Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, graphics-tablet

I have a Lenovo monitor that's 23 inches and a new UGEE graphics tablet that has a monitor screen of 19 inches. I purchased the graphics tablet a few days ago and I'm having some difficulties on how the dual-screen works. My UGEE tablet doesn't have an HDMI port, it only has a VGA port and a DVI port. I have the VGA cord, but I don't have a DVI cord. I also have an HDMI cord, but I feel that it's irrelevant to my current issue considering my graphics tablet doesn't have a spot to plug in a HDMI cable.

So, my question here is, how in the world do I hook up the two monitors so that they both display my computer screen. Do I need the DVI cord to HDMI cord and connect the DVI end to my tablet and the HDMI end to my tower?

Or is it possible that my Lenovo monitor doesn't support dual screens? This would be very disappointing and I'm hoping that's not the case, my Lenovo monitor is one of their newest models that I purchased from Best Buy. The model my Lenovo monitor is **LI2364D**.

As of right now, I have the VGA cord plugged into my tablet and the other end plugged into the VGA port of my monitor. And the outcome is, of course, a black tablet screen. So, am I doing something wrong or is my solution a DVI to HDMI cord?

Comment: What you required entirely depends on your hardware.  What display inputs do you have besides HDMI?  The tablet needs to be connected to your PC not your monitor.  If you tell us what you purchased exactly we can help.

Comment: The display inputs I have on my tower are the VGA port, a few USB ports, and a spot for an Ethernet cord. I'm not seeing any other ports similar to a VGA. On the back of my graphics tablet, I have one USB port, VGA port, and a DVI port. The dual-screens are now "working" but only somewhat. The issue now is that my desktop background is showing on both monitors, but my tablet's monitor isn't opening and showing programs like my Lenovo monitor. My Lenovo monitor is now hooked up to the tower by an HDMI cord and my tablet is hooked up to the tower with the VGA cord.

Comment: Also, the tablet that I purchased and the model of it is UGEE UG-1910B 19" monitor.

Comment: You just contradicted yourself.  You said you were not finding a VGA port on the back of the tablet, then indicated, there is a VGA port.  If you have a VGA port on your tower, and a VGA port on the tablet, just connect the two with a VGA cable.

Answer (score 1):

The VGA port on your monitor goes into your *pc*. There's interfaces that daisy chain but VGA is not one.

"My tower" - indicates a proper PC. You need to plug both the monitor and the tablet into that. *If* necessary, you might need an adaptor - there's HDMI or DP in on the PC to vga or HDMI in the monitor side adaptors.

One does not typically plug a monitor into another monitor and expect it to work in most cases.

Comment: Okay, so I did figure that out yesterday but I'm still having issues. The dual-screens are working, only somewhat, though. My tablet is showing my desktop screen, but whenever I open any of my programs (firefox, photoshop, sai, etc.) none of them are opening or showing on my tablet's monitor but the programs are showing and opening on my Lenovo monitor. As of right now, my tablet is connected by the VGA port to the tower, my Lenovo monitor is hooked into my tower by a HDMI. So, even with the monitors not connected to each other and only connected to the tower, it's still not working properly.

Comment: You have to change the order of the displays.  Just drag the window to the tablet display manually.